# How to check returned value to which function it belogns

Tags: php

Say I have to similar function :

```
public function auth(){

  return $someResponse;
}

public function collect(){

 return $someOtherResponse
}
```

Question : When one of the response get passed to another class, is there any way to check which function returned the response ?

Comment: No. *[11 more characters]*

Comment: Return a value that carries meaning in itself, not something that you need to track back to something to infer something.

Comment: @deceze alright thanks

Comment: You can return flag like 1 or 2 to differentiate each function response.

Comment: @JinandraGupta the thing is that I dont want to do it the ugly way!

Comment: In the auth function, you could do; `return (array("auth" => $someresponse))` and in the collect; `return (array("collect" => $someotherresponse))` The in the class, `if (isset($response['auth'])) {/* auth res */} else if (isset($response['collect'])) {/* collect response */}`

Comment: What is "the ugly way"?

Comment: Without any context as to what those two functions actually return and how those values are being used, it's hard to come up with a suitable solution

Comment: @deceze  what do you mean, I dont understand you

Comment: [*"I dont want to do it the ugly way!"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156393/how-to-check-returned-value-to-which-function-it-belogns?noredirect=1#comment87330590_50156393) – What is "the ugly way"?

Comment: You probably have an XY problem and are asking the wrong question. What is your intent? What are you trying to achieve by this? More information is needed to be helpful. (XY-Problem: You have to accomplish X and determin early on that Y is the way -- asking here about Y; if the community knew X, the better Solution Z could be presented)

Comment: @deceze Indian style code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a purely object-oriented way, wanting to attach information to a value is akin to wrapping it into a container possessing context information, such as:

```
class ValueWithContext {
    private $value;
    private $context;

    public function __construct($value, $context) {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public value() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public context() {
        return $this->context;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
function auth()
{
    return new ValueWithContext($someresponse, "auth");
}

function collect()
{
    return new ValueWithContext($someotherrpesonse, "collect");
}
```

This forces you to be explicit about the context attached to the value, which has the benefit of protecting you from accidental renamings of the functions themselves.

Comment: thats the exact way how I did go with that before even checking your answer! I was mostly looking to avoid FP way of doing it with a better OOP way. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, using arrays in the return will give you a viable solution to this.

It will allow a way to see what has been done;

```
function auth()
{
    return (array("auth" => $someresponse));
}

function collect()
{
    return (array("collect" => $someotherrpesonse));
}

class myClass
{
    function doSomething($type)
    {
        if (function_exists($type))
        {
            $result = $type();

            if (isset($result['auth']))
            {
                // Auth Used
                $auth_result = $result['auth'];
            }
            else if (isset($result['collect']))
            {
                // Collect used
                $collect_result = $result['collect'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can also give you a way to fail by having a `return array("fail" => "fail reason")`

As comments say also, you can just check based on function name;

```
class myClass
{
    function doSomething($type)
    {
        switch ($type)
        {
            case "auth" :
            {
                $result = auth();
                break;
            }
            case "collect" :
            {
                $result = collect();
                break;
            }
            default :
            {
                // Some error occurred?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either way works and is perfectly valid!

Comment: Our of curiosity, why do you have parentheses around the return values?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's a habit more than anything, not needed, I just like them

Comment: Btw, I don't really get the point of returning arrays at all. You already have the function name in `$type`, no? You could just as easily have done `if ('auth' === $type)` directly.

Comment: Yes - but the OP was asking how to do it from the function, not the name of the function, so that's my workaround, regardless, you're using a series of "if's" and as per bottom, arrays give you a fail response option :)

Comment: There would literally be no difference if you compared `$type` instead (and skipped the arrays).

Comment: Apart from the ability to have `return (array("fail" => "reason"));` as a return value :)

Comment: Look at the logic, you're currently checking the array result for the function name instead of the type. If the array has the function name, you're still only getting the value. So skipping the array would allow you to do the exact same thing. Sure, if the "forget" an if, they would get an array with the function name, but then they would get an array instead of the actual value, which would be a much worse issue.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, purely that my point in this **specific** example is - you can't check for a failed result if you just check function name - you'd have to do further error handling within the function, this just skips that out, potential time and power saver

Answer (score -1):

Letting the two user defined functions `auth()` & `collect()` call a common function which makes a call to `debug_backtrace()` function should do the trick.

```
function setBackTrace(){
    $backTraceData = debug_backtrace();
    $traceObject = array_reduce($backTraceData, function ($str, $val2) {
        if (trim($str) === "") {
            return $val2['function'];
        }
        return $str . " -> " . $val2['function'];
    });
    return $traceObject;
}

function getfunctionDo1(){
    return setBackTrace();
}


function getfunctionDo2(){
    return setBackTrace();
}

class DoSomething {

    static function callfunctionTodo($type){
        return (($type === 1) ? getfunctionDo1() : getfunctionDo2());
    }
}

echo DoSomething::callfunctionTodo(1);
echo "<br/>";
echo DoSomething::callfunctionTodo(2);

/*Output
setBackTrace -> getfunctionDo1 -> callfunctionTodo
setBackTrace -> getfunctionDo2 -> callfunctionTodo
*/
```

The above function would output the which function returned the response